# Avoid retain cycles in closures using weak self

Tags: ios, swift, closures, retain-cycle

We were having this debate at work about what's the best way to avoid retain cycle in a closure. We were debating following two approaches.

```
    func getStock() { [weak self] (stock)in
       self?.dismissActivityIndicator()
    }
```

vs

```
    func getStock(){ [weak self] (stock) in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      strongSelf.dismissActicityIndicator()
    }
```

Is one of them better or safer than the other? Why? Our discussion was based on multithreaded scenarios if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In practice there is no difference between the two approaches.

Optional chaining `self?.` exits the closure if `self` is `nil` as well as `guard let ... else {`

Comment: That's what I thought too, but things get trickier when you have multiple statements in the closure. if one operation modifies self, the other operation would know in case of self?. However, in case of guard let strongSelf, strongSelf doesn't change even if one of the operations change self. I know it sounds confusing, I can try putting it in code here, I am not sure how to out code in the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

For simple closures, like your single-line example, there really is no difference between the two approaches; so the variant with the weak reference can be considered "better" because it's easier to read and takes one line less (but in the end it's a matter of taste).

When your closure gets complex, the second approach is more deterministic: e.g. you could call another asynchronous method inside your closure and access `strongSelf` from within the nested callback block, and be sure that the object still exists; with a weak `self` it's possible that the object gets released before that nested callback runs.

With great power comes great responsibility though; keeping the object alive by force is not always what you want -- e.g. when `self` is a `UIViewController`, it might just be the desired behaviour to *not* retain it in a callback: if the VC was removed from the view hierarchy it's probably better to also discard the result of any pending background operation than to update a UI which never will be shown. You can even decide whether or not to cancel your background work early based on the weak object's existence. (Of course having such complex closures is not something I'd advocate, except for the sake of example.)